# Android manage emulator from command line

Tags: android, automation, android-emulator

Is there a way to:

1) open Android emulator;

2) install my apk-file there;

3) run application on the emulator and perform some actions (for example, click on the buttons, type text into EditText etc).

**I'm wondering is there a way to do all of this automatically, in some kind of script?**
Or maybe there is some testing tool, where you can point list of actions, in order not to test manually every new build.

Comment: 1.) https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html 2.) https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#move 3.) https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Comment: You may want to read about UIAutomator: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator